# Getting "detached HEAD" error despite deleting git submodule

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github, git-submodules

Git seems to be tracking the java folder, but I can't commit changes to the specific file `MainActivity.java`. I get a "Changes not staged for commit"
The diff shows the changes, but I can't commit it.

Also, I can't go down into the folder in Github.

[image: Project structure]
[image: Commit error]

[image: Github structure]
That folder is not clickable.

**Edit:** When I do `git status` in the command line, I get

```
user:JustJava juil$ git status
HEAD detached at 93ea9a1
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava (modified content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

**Edit 2:** I have checked out the latest commit as some have suggested but still get the detached head error.

[image: Current git log]

**Edit 3:** I tried adding the file itself w/ `git add` but got an error that the directory is a submodule.

```
JustJava juil$ git add app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava/MainActivity.java
fatal: Pathspec 'app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava/MainActivity.java' is in submodule 'app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava'
```

I tried running `git submodule status` and got the error

```
fatal: no submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava'
```

I tried deleting `.git` in the submodule, but the same error keeps popping up.

Comment: You are in a detached state. Run `git status` in command line and post the result

Comment: I've put the output of `git status` in the question, but it still doesn't explain why I can't access the files on Github.

Comment: Try: `git stash`, `git checkout master`, `git stash pop`. Then you can commit your changes and continue working on master

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler Tried this, but it doesn't register my changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `justjava` folder turned out to be a submodule, in the super directory, I called `git rm -rf --cached justjava` as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824611/androidstudio-is-not-committing-mainactivity-java-to-github/37849877#comment63157637_37825916) by @fusiongate and answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260982/745776).

This works in that it allows the file to be added and committed, but the commit history on this file is lost.

Answer (score 0):

To correct this using just the Android Studio interface, try the following:

1. Make a backup copy of your changed files, just in case this method doesn't merge your changes correctly.
2. In the version control pane, select the `Log` tab. It will show you a list of commits.
3. The top commit should be the newest one. Right click it and select `Checkout Revision` in the context menu.
4. If a dialog appears, select `Smart Checkout`. This will merge your changes with the selected commit.
5. Your HEAD should now be attached, so you can commit normally now.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't do anything. I have updated the question with a screenshot of my current git log.

Comment: It looks like MainActivity.java was never actually added to git. Try doing `git add app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava/MainActivity.java`

Comment: Tried it but got a submodule error. Updated in the question.

Comment: You might try one of these answers to remove the submodule: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule/) but it may be as simple as `git rm -rf --cached justjava`

Answer (score 0):

When your HEAD is detached, it means you did the commandline equivalent of:

```
git checkout <UUID of previous commit>
```

The grey folder that was created is called a submodule, it happens when you initialize a git repository inside another git repository. I would suggest removing the .git folder inside `JustJava/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava`.

Using git through terminal, follow these steps:

1. **Backup all the code in a different folder**
2. **Remove JustJava/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/justjava/.git"
3. **Checkout out master or the current branch you're on (default: master)**

   In order to checkout master, go to the folder where you git project is through the terminal (linux or mac) or [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) (if you're on windows), then do:

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
4. **Comparing backed up code with the current code and make the changes you want (if any)**
5. **Commit new code**

Comment: I tried checking out the master, but still got the same errors as stated in my newest edit to my question.